# If my value is stored in a Thread Safe map does the value need to be ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-transactions

I'm storing objects in a `ThreadLocal` `Map` ( implemented in spring-tx)

```
class TransactionSynchronizationManager ...

private static final ThreadLocal<Map<Object, Object>> resources =
        new NamedThreadLocal<Map<Object, Object>>("Transactional resources");
```

if the Map is `ThreadLocal` and properly accessed (again all spring-tx code), do the values I store in the map have to be ThreadLocal to be thread safe?

Comment: If it's thread local why does it need to be synchronized at all?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't mean `synchronized` in the sense of the keyword, or maybe I do... the map isn't my implementation, I'm just sticking values in it, I'm just trying to convey that all access to the map itself is thread safe

Comment: Which threads are accessing the map?

Comment: Then it depends on how you deal with objects in the map. For example, if you have a reference from the map that you retrieved in a thread-safe manner, how do you modify that reference? Objects *in* a thread-safe map aren't thread-safe, *access to the map* is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you haven't inadvertently passed the Map to another thread by some other means, the Map does not need any additional protection, because all usage of it will be single-threaded.  Likewise, as long as any Objects in the Map are not inadvertently passed to other threads by other means, those Objects do not need any additional protection.